# Obvious type conversion VS implicit type conversion

Tags: c

I have a lot of type conversions in my code, for example

```
#define static_cast(T,V) ((T)(V))
typedef unsigned char   Uint8_T;
typedef int             Bool_T;

...

Bool_T folder = true;

...

Uint8_T smth = folder;
```

my question is, what is better to leave this code like this, or use obvious type conversion, for example

```
Uint8_T smth = static_cast(Uint8_T, folder);
```

p.s. In the case of conversion from bigger type to lesser I exactly know that things will be ok.

Comment: You mean type conversion perhaps..

Comment: +1 you probably mean 'explicit type conversion' vs 'implicit type conversion'.

Comment: Prefer explicit to implicit, it makes your intention *obvious*.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should use explicit casting when you cast, so how ever review your code (can be you after a long time you didn't see it) will know you did what you did on purpose and that you knew what you were doing.